# How can an Attribute prevent the execution of an MVC Action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, custom-attributes, outputcache

In `MVC` an `OutputCacheAttribute` is capable to prevent the execution of the action it is decorating (if the relative cache exists)

How to implement the same mechanism with a custom attribute?

In other works I would like to be able to decorate an action, and based on a logic internal to the attribute it will decide whether the action should carry on executing or not.

**Additions**

I've implemented a mechanism by which if a request to an action arrives with a querystring like `flushaction=flush_silent`, the custom attribute (which is extending the `OutputCacheAttribute`) invalidates the cache.

What I would also like to do, is not to execute the Action:

```
[JHOutputCache(CacheProfile = "ContentPageController.Index")]
public ActionResult Index(string url)
{
     //custom code that should not execute when flushing the cache
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `JHOutputCache` extends `OutputCacheAttribute`, which derives from `ActionFilterAttribute`, halting execution of the underlying action is quite simple:

```
public class JHOutputCacheAttribute : OutputCacheAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (condition)
            filterContext.Result = new EmptyResult();
        else
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

You can return any valid [ActionResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) here, including any custom `ActionResult` you may have derived.

Comment: I'm having another issue, the problem is that the actual request with the `flushaction=flush_silent` gets cached and it won't execute a second time. Do you know how to prevent it to be cached from within the Attribute itself? I can setup another question if easier.

Comment: @GiuseppeR It's a little difficult to tell what you're trying to do, but it sounds as though [VaryByParam](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might be what you need to look at.

Comment: I've setup another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21193335/how-to-programmatically-prevent-the-executing-action-to-be-cached-when-there-is